# Set object property after asynchronous call in node

Tags: node.js, callback, singleton, node-modules

How do I create a nodejs module which sends a post request to a url and returns an object who's data property is set to be the data returned from the post request?

```
var client = require('node-rest-client').Client();

module.exports = (function(){
    var instance;

    function createInstance(){
        client.post(url,function(data){
            //set instance.data = data OR
            // return function that lets me access a private property 'data' set to data returned in this callback
        });
    }

    return {
        Cloud : function(){
            if(!instance){
                instance = createInstance();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT:

Basically when i call the above module and execute the Cloud function :

var cloud = require('module').Cloud();
console.log(cloud.data); //should give me data received from the post request.
//ALSO I want to do this using the module pattern, with the post request inside the module.

Comment: Do you mean you want to fetch some data over HTTP POST to a particular url? What kind of the return data? JSON, XML, etc?

Comment: You can't directly return the result of an async operation from your module function.  Instead, you can have the caller pass in a callback that will be called with the result of the async operation or you can return a promise that will be resolved with the result when the async operation completes.

Comment: As already said, what you want is impossible. You have to do it another way (callback or promise).

Comment: what if i send the object to the function instead : so Cloud : function(obj), and the callback sets the obj's properties. Is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a promise e.g. :

```
function postReq() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       client.post(url, function(data) {
           resolve(data);
       })
    });
}

postReq()
.then(function(data) {
  // Do whatever you want with the data returned from client.post
  console.log(data);  
})
```